# How to add content to suscriptor dashboard frontend?

Tags: hooks, dashboard

I'm learning plugins development.

Just with learning pourposes. I want to add some content on the suscriptor user dashboard.

I thought that may be with some hook called on the user dashboard I could add some content, but I have no idea how to find it or if this is a the correct approach.

PD:I'm trying with Query Monitor plugin but it gives me so many hooks that I get lost.

Comment: Sometimes the best method is to open the plugin folder in your favorite editor and search for `do_action()` or `apply_filters()`

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful filter on [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) for the hooks.

And I have found `woocommerce_account_content` and does did the trick.